# pam_unix logs: xrdp-sesman:session session opened for user USERNAME(uid) by (uid=0)

Tags: logging, pam, xrdp

recently I found a lot of these type of logs:

```
pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session opened for user username(uid=some_uid) by (uid=0)
```

From what I read is `xrdp-sesmam-session` that is "opening" the session to username, so it seems just a normal log for an xrdp session.

My doubt is that the system was not upgraded and the configuration is the same but only recently I find this in logs and for sure all the logs entries doesn't cover all the xrdp session that were used, it's a bit strange, if someone has any hints about why is this happening.

Thanks for the help